# pip install git+https://bitbucket.company.com/path/to/package.git is not installing dependencies from requirements.txt

Tags: pip, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, hatch

I am trying to install a python package from my organization's Bitbucket instance which I have been developing using the below commands:

```
$ python -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install git+https://bitbucket.company.com/path/to/package.git
```

Even though I was able to install my python `package` into `venv` but I was expecting it to install the necessary dependencies which I have specified in `requirements.txt` also!!!

What all changes I need to make to my python `package` to install the dependencies also?

Below is my `package` project structure:

```
.
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── src
│   └── package
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── main.py
└── tests
    └── test_dummy.py
```

N.b., I am using `hatchling` for building my python `package`

Comment: Did you specify in `pyproject.toml` to install requirements.txt? `but I was expecting it` Why were you expecting it? Did you read documentation that it would do that?

Comment: For *pip* (and any other installer) to automatically installed the dependencies, these dependencies have to be listed in the project's packaging metadata (not in `requirements.txt`). The way to do it is to write the list of [dependencies in `pyproject.toml`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#dependencies-optional-dependencies) (aside: make sure to only list the direct dependencies and use only loose version constraints).

Answer (score 2):

For *pip* (and other installers) to automatically install the dependencies of the project along the project itself, the dependencies have to be listed in the project's packaging metadata (not in `requirements.txt`). The way to do it is to write the list of [dependencies in `pyproject.toml`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#dependencies-optional-dependencies)

*Aside*: Make sure to only list the direct dependencies and use only loose version constraints (no pinned dependencies in project packaging metadata, the pinned dependencies belong in `requirements.txt` only). You can find some discussion about this topic [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/) (it is a bit outdated, but the concept of "abstract vs. concrete dependencies" still holds).

For *Hatch* (and *hatchling*) specifically there is [documentation about dependencies here](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/dependency/), but since this follows a [standard specification](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#dependencies-optional-dependencies), you can find it documented in many other places.